# Android Webview Duplicate Files when Selecting Image

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm having a problem with uploading files on android webview which occurs when I select a file or camera to select then a CAPUTURE_OOOOOOOO.jpg file is formed which should only be formed when I manage to take a photo and take the image into the selected image file, here's the code with kotlin

```
myWebView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams):Boolean {
            chooserCallback = filePathCallback
            
            val fileCamera = File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                ), "CAPTURE_" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg"
            )
            chooserCamera = Uri.fromFile(fileCamera)

            val captureIntent =  Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, chooserCamera)

            val imageIntent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            imageIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            imageIntent.type = "image/*"

            val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(imageIntent, "Select Image")
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(captureIntent))
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, requestChooser)
            return true
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == requestChooser) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.v("chooserCamera", data?.dataString.toString())
            Log.v("dataString", data?.dataString.toString())
            val result: Uri = if (data?.dataString == null)  chooserCamera as Uri else data.data as Uri
            chooserCallback?.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(result))
            chooserCallback = null
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            chooserCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
            chooserCallback = null
        }
    }
}
```

the CAPUTURE_OOOOOOOO.jpg file should only be formed when I take a photo with the camera and select it, not when I press the choose button so there is a duplication of files in this process, thank you

video recorded from virtual devices - Nexus 5 Api 30 : https://streamable.com/0kylsu

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would create that file. Further the used Camera app will not be able to create that file too as Uri.fromFile() is not usable Since Android 7/N.

Comment: Further its unclear why you mess around with ACTION_GET_CONTENT while taking a picture.

Comment: @blackapps you can watch this video https://streamable.com/0kylsu

Comment: @adyoi if you expect to be helped, you might consider taking the extra time to *extract all relevant info into your question* instead of prompting potential helpful people to watch videos...

Answer (score 0):

```
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
        // onActivityResult attached before constructor
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }


        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //For Android 4.1 only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you use kotlin